# Alamofire result from NSMutableDictionary to Array of String : Anyobject

Tags: swift, nsmutabledictionary, alamofire

I am making a request via alamofire which is receiving this as a response:

```
{
success: true,
data: [
{
_id: "5615dd59e4b0d2d408b385ff",
name: "Exam Prep",
info: "Tools designed to increase students' performance on standardized tests",
active: true
},
{
_id: "5615dd75e4b0d2d408b38603",
name: "Mathematics",
info: "The study of topics such as quantity numbers, structure, space, and change",
active: true
},
{
_id: "5615dd8de4b0d2d408b38604",
name: "Science",
info: "Knowledge in the form of predictions about the universe",
active: true
},
{
_id: "5615dda5e4b0d2d408b38605",
name: "Language Arts",
info: "The study of languages, composition, and grammar",
active: true
}
]
}
```

Using the generic object serialization as a template form Alamofire's documentation: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/2.0.2/ my subject class has the following method:

```
static func collection(response response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [Subject] {
    var subjects: [Subject] = []

    if let representation = representation as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        for subjectRepresentation in representation {
            if let subject = Subject(response: response, representation: subjectRepresentation) {
                subjects.append(subject)
            }
        }
    }

    return subjects
}
```

However the cast of if let representation = representation as? [[String: AnyObject]] always fails. I believe this has something to do with the json data being in "data" rather than the root level object but I am clueless as how to tell the cast to pull out the "data" element to make instances of the Subject class. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull out `data` element using `valueForKeyPath` :

```
static func collection(response response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [Subject] {
var subjects: [Subject] = []

if let representation = representation.valueForKeyPath("data") as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    for subjectRepresentation in representation {
        if let subject = Subject(response: response, representation: subjectRepresentation) {
            subjects.append(subject)
        }
    }
}

return subjects
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast `representation` as `[String: AnyObject]`

```
let representation = representation as? [String: AnyObject]
```